# significance of address 0x8048080

Tags: linux, x86, gdb, ld, memory-layout

why when i debug asm source in gdb is 0x8048080 the address chosen for the starting entry point into code? this is just a relative offset, not an actual offset of into memory of an instruction, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no special significance to address `0x8048080`, but there is one for address `0x08048000`.

The latter address is the default address, on which `ld` starts the first `PT_LOAD` segment on Linux/x86. On Linux/x86_64, the default is `0x400000`, and you can change the default by using a "custom" linker script. You can also change where `.text` section starts with `-Wl,-Ttext,0xNNNNNNNN` flag.

After `ld` starts at `0x08048000`, it adds space for program headers, and proceeds to link the rest of the executable according to its built-in linker script, which you can see if you pass in `-Wl,--verbose` to your link line.

For *your* program, the size of program headers appears to always be `0x80`, so your `.text` section always starts at `0x8048080`, but that is by no means universal.

When I link a trivial `int main() { return 0; }` program, I get `&_start == &.text` at `0x8048300`, `0x8048178` or `0x8048360`, depending on which compiler I use.

Comment: On x86-64, current `ld` (e.g. GNU binutils 2.34.0) places the start of the text segment (for non-PIE executable) at `0x401000`, not `0x400000`.  (With a PLT before it, `_start` usually ends up somewhat after that, e.g. `0x401080`)  But I think this changed at some point, I seem to recall older `ld` putting the start of "text" at some thing like `0x400080` even in a static executable built from one asm instruction?  And there were some ELF headers before it in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

0×8048080 is the default entry point in virtual memory used by the Linux ld linker. You can change it to whatever you want.

for more details check out: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/01/27/how-debuggers-work-part-2-breakpoints/

Comment: thank you! very interesting link, just what i was looking for :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The 'ld' does *not* place default entry point at any predetermined address.